# Экспорт данных с таблицы в файл через bcp

Tags: sql, sql-server

Что следует поменять?

```
Declare @export varchar(500),
@query varchar(500) = '"Select * from ZKZS.dbo.MemberofCommittee"'


set @export = 'bcp ' + @query + 'queryout C:\Users\anvar\OneDrive\Базы Данных\Курсовая\Импорт и экспорт данных\Экспорт ЧК в файл.xml'
 execute xp_cmdshell @export
```

Выводит результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Путь к файлу содержит пробелы. Возьмите его в кавычки.

Comment: но то же самое происходит